# jQuery Is it possible to fall through statusCode?

Tags: jquery

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to fall through one status code to the next with jquery statusCode so that one response can be handle 2 status codes? The code below has an error but it shows what I'm trying to achieve... 400 falls through to 404.

```
    ,statusCode: {
         200: function (response) {
            alert('200');
        }
        ,201: function (response) {
            alert('201');
        }
        ,400:
        ,404: function (response) {
            alert('400 or 404');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Heh, not a switch case.  You could declare your statusCode/handler map externally and do something like `statusCode.400 = statusCode.404 = function(resp) { ... };`

Answer (score 1):

The best you might be able to do is to name the anonymous function and pass a reference to that function into the `statusCode` object:

```
var badRequestOrNotFound = function () {
    alert('400 or 404');
};

$.ajax({
    statusCode: {
        200: function (response) {
            alert('200');
        }
        ,201: function (response) {
            alert('201');
        }
        ,400: badRequestOrNotFound
        ,404: badRequestOrNotFound
    }
});
```

You could also abandon the `statusCode` option completely and leverage the `status` property of the `xhr` parameter the `error` callback gets passed:

```
$.ajax({
    error: function (xhr) {
        switch (xhr.status) {
            case 404:
            case 400:
                alert('400 or 404');
                break;
            case 200:
                alert('200');
                break;
            case 201:
                alert('201');
                break;
        }
    }
});
```